# ActionScript3 - Почему не отображается текст?

Tags: actionscript

В main у меня создаются кнопки, при нажатии на кнопку у меня вот такой вызов функции:

```
var TxtAbt:TextInfo = new TextInfo();
TxtAbt.AboutF();
```

В самой функции:

```
public function AboutF()
{
    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
    var AboutText = new TextField();

    myFormat.align = "center";
    myFormat.font = "Tahoma";
    myFormat.size = 25;
    myFormat.color = 0xAA00FF;  

    AboutText.width = 120;
    AboutText.height = 40;
    AboutText.y = 5;
    AboutText.selectable = false;
    AboutText.text = "Текс будет здесь, много текста";
    AboutText.setTextFormat(myFormat);
    addChild(AboutText);
    trace("ABOUT TEXT");
}
```

Но почему то на сцене не вижу текст, хотя `trace` проходит, ошибок нет.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, забыл сделать `addChild(TxtAbt)`

```
var TxtAbt:TextInfo = new TextInfo();
TxtAbt.AboutF();
addChild(TxtAbt);
```